# Кто может помочь с настройкой модуля telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

**Помогите пожалуйста настроить модуль в моем коде**

```
import random
import telebot

bot =telebot.TeleBot("API", parse_mode=None)

# Доки

 output = input("Какой жанр фильма вам нужен ? ")

list0 = ["Остров проклятых ", "Платформа ", "Бегущий в лабиринте", "Невидимый Гость", "Джокер"]  # Триллер

list2 = ["Полтора шпиона", "Почему он ?", "Дедпул", "Приключения Паддингтона", "Джуманджи"]  # Комедия

list3 = ["До встречи с тобой", "Пассажиры", "Призрачная красота", "Виноваты звезды", "Великий Гэтсби"]  # Драма

list4 = ["Пустой человек", "Проклятие плачущей", "Ня Ня", "Проклятие монахини", "Заклятие"]  # Ужасы

list5 = ["Социальная Сеть", "В погоне за счастем", "Стив Джобс", "Тёмные времена", "Толкин", "Основатель"]  # Бигроф

list6 = ["Люси", "Варкрафт", "Лара Крофт", "Веном", "Довод", "Рэмпейдж", "Хищник"]  # Боевик

list7 = ["Дюнкерк", "Монгол", "Викинг", "По соображениям совести", "1917", "Линкольн"]  # Исторический

list8 = ["Зверополис", "Немо", "Головоломка", "Унесённые призраками", "Город героев", "Ральф"]  # Мультфильм

list9 = ["Гангстер", "Хороший лжец", "Схватка", "Джокер", "Правдивая история", "Исчезнувшая"]  # Криминал

list10 = ["ERROR ANIME GOVNO ERROR"]  # Аниме

list11 = ["Толкин", "Волк С Вол Стрит", "Игра на понижение", "Время", "Человек который познал ",
    "В погоне за счастием ", "Призрачноя красота", "Легенда", "Социальная сеть", "Ликольн Адвокат",
    "Остров проклятых"]  # Топ 10

# Условия

if output == "Триллер":
print(random.choice(list0))

elif output == "Комедия":
print(random.choice(list2))

elif output == "Драма":
print(random.choice(list3))

elif output == "Ужасы":
print(random.choice(list4))

elif output == "Биографические":
print(random.choice(list5))

elif output == "Боевик":
print(random.choice(list6))

elif output == "Исторический":
print(random.choice(list7))

elif output == "Мультфильм":
print(random.choice(list8))

elif output == "Криминальные":
print(random.choice(list9))

elif output == "Аниме":
print(random.choice(list10))

elif output == "Топ 10" or "Топ-10" or "Топ10":
print(random.choice(list11))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Читайте внимательно документацию! Скопируйте и попробуйте готовый пример. `input()` и `print()` используются только для работы с командной строкой. У telebot-а свои функции.